# What role of adapter, service, content provider and other basic elements in MVP architecture of android app?

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture, mvp

I figure out that it's very useful to use MVP pattern in my apps, but it's too complicated for me, how find out of role elements in apps, which is model, view, presenter?

1. What is adapter of recyclerview? I guess it should be a view, but it manage loading data to recyclerview, so it can be also presenter or model
2. How many presenters can have view? What is basic? For one view should be one present and one model? But if I have some view and can they use one presenter?
3. I have an app with recyclerview which is loading images from rest api. I wanna figure out elements for MVP. Activity with recycler view is View? Adapter is Presenter? Picasso is Model? Retrofit is Model? Notification Service for download in external storage is Model? Image class is Model?
4. Can you please give a link for big complex apps with MVP architecture, please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no agreed definition on exactly the best way of MVP-ing in Android.

My answers to your questions.

1. I'd say the Adapter is a View, that is passed data from a **Presenter**.
2. I usually have 1 Presenter 1 View.
3. **View**: RecyclerView, Actvity, Fragment + Adpater all are views for me. Presenter: Is a normal java class that retrieves the data from **Model** (Retrofit, Sqlite, ContentProvider) and gives it the **View** to populate the RecyclerView.

See this article on [MVP](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/)

**Note**:

- Try to ensure the Presenter does not have any Android logic or Android stuff.
- Model doesn't just mean the POJO's it can mean include storing in DB, ContentProvider etc. including network retrieval.
- The View should not interact with the model directly i.e. data retrieval, storage etc. **Only** via the Presenter.

Comment: How you said adapter and activity are views, how they interact with presents through each other or they have two different references for presenter?

Comment: 1) Read the article above 2) The Activity will hold reference to the Presenter as a member variable and so will be able to call methods in the presenter. But really read the article linked above.

Comment: Thank you, guess, I start to get it, now, do you know good examples with Dagger 2 + MVP? I read a few, not clear for me.